# VBA Excel Dynamic Charts using For Loop even odd columns

Tags: vba, loops, dynamic, for-loop, charts

Please see the code below:

```
Sub CreatePieCharts()

'Declare the variables

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim AddtionalCharts As Chart
    Dim MySeries As Series
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim CatRange As Range
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim SourceData As Range
    Dim LeftPos As Double
    Dim TopPos As Double
    Dim Gap As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long

    'Set the range for the source data from the active worksheet
    Set Rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    'Set the position of the first chart
    LeftPos = Range("M3").Left
    TopPos = Range("M3").Top

    'Set the gap between charts
    Gap = 5

    'Set the range for the category values
    For j = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
        For i = 2 To Rng.Columns.Count

            If j Mod 2 = 1 And i Mod 2 = 0 Then _
                Set SourceData = Union(Rng.Columns(j), Rng.Columns(i))

            'Create the pie charts

            Set AddtionalCharts = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
            With AddtionalCharts
                .SetSourceData SourceData, xlColumns
                .ChartType = xlPie
                .ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowValue, False
                .Parent.Left = LeftPos
                .Parent.Top = TopPos
                TopPos = TopPos + .Parent.Height + Gap
            End With
        Next i
    Next j

End Sub
```

Basically, the macro needs to loop through the columns and create charts based on the columns even or odd state. For example: Chart1 and Answer 1 should be one chart, Chart2 and Answer2 should be the next one and so on.

Right now I am able to create the charts but for some reason there are some other extra charts that show which I don't need. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to include the pie chart creation bit into your `If` construct. Right now it isn't, so a chart gets created no matter what.

What you're doing is this:

```
If <condition> Then <statement1>

<statement2>
```

Here, `<statement2>` will always be executed regardless of `<condition>`.

Do this instead:

```
If <condition> Then
    <statement1>
    <statement2>
    '...
End If
```

In this case, `<statement2>` only gets executed (along with `<statement1>`) if `<condition>` is satisfied.

In your specific case:

```
            If j Mod 2 = 1 And i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                Set SourceData = Union(Rng.Columns(j), Rng.Columns(i))
                'Create the pie charts
                Set AddtionalCharts = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
                With AddtionalCharts
                    .SetSourceData SourceData, xlColumns
                    .ChartType = xlPie
                    .ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowValue, False
                    .Parent.Left = LeftPos
                    .Parent.Top = TopPos
                    TopPos = TopPos + .Parent.Height + Gap
                End With
            End If
```